# Why does tail command displays only two records from the bottom?

Tags: linux, shell, command, tail

[image]

Your help will be really appreciated

Comment: Do you just have an empty new line at the end of `cars`?

Comment: The last line in file is empty and tail is showing that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I don't have any empty line at the end of cars.@Kevin

Comment: Please state the output and the errors. The text on the picture cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cars` files ends with a blank line, as can be seen when you `cat` it. Thus, `tail -3 cars` prints the last three lines in the file: `Cadillac`, `Ford` and an empty line.

Comment: I placed the cursor right after the Ford and tried the tail command but still showing the same output.

Answer (score -1):

As the others said, you need to delete the empty line.  Open the file, place the cursor below Ford and hit backspace, save the file and try again.

Comment: That last ‘return’ is pretty significant.  Maybe give everyone some credit by tapping their up triangles.

Comment: Hi  @J.Doe can you explain this to me ?  $ cat cars
Ferrari
Porsche
Merc
BMW
Honda
Toyota
Nissan
 $ tail -3  cars
Honda
Toyota
Nissan
 $ tail +3  cars
Merc
BMW
Honda
Toyota
Nissan
 Why is it showing a different output in tail +3 cars?

Comment: Type ‘man cat’ and see what that says.  Try ‘man tail’

Comment: My implementation may be a little different than yours, it does not like ‘tail +3 cars’ it wants ‘tail -n +3 cars’ ... but in that case it is starting at the third item and proceeding to the end, as you obtained.  Give a little credit to those that have helped you.

Comment: Yeah, bipin, I really appreciate that